# Add Formula To Function In Google Scripts Editor

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using existing code, need to add dynamic formula to a function.

Script is designed for simple time tracking, start/stop time tracking with buttons in google sheets.

```js
function setValue(cellName, value {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellName).setValue(value);
  }

  function getValue(cellName) {
    return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellName).getValue();
  }

  function getNextRow() {
    return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getLastRow() + 1;
  }

  function addRecord(a, b, c, d) {
    var row = getNextRow();
    setValue('A' + row, a);
    setValue('B' + row, b);
    setValue('C' + row, c);
    setValue('D' + row, d);
  }

  function punchIn() {
    addRecord(getValue('A1'), new Date(), 'START', (""));
  }

  function punchOut() {
    addRecord(getValue('A1'), new Date(), 'STOP', (""));
  }
```

In the punchOut function value D, I want to subtract the STOP time from the prior START time. In theory, it should just be cell D in current row minus cell D in prior row vs getting complicated & looking for the START time from the same day in a prior row. So, just D in current row minus D in prior row?

Here is a picture of output, although with a manual formula in column D.[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rI9j.png)

Answer (score 1):

Google Apps Script is based on JavaScript so you could use the last to make arithmetic operations like additions and subtractions.

- Use `getActiveRange()` to get the active range.
- Use `offset(...)` to get the previous row

Once you get the desired values, let say `value1`, `value2`, just add a code line like this:

```
var result = value2 - value1;
```

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I'm not following though how I would make a new function (?) and then add it into the punchOut 4 segment/column after STOP?

Comment: @LevGrodzinskiy Please edit your question to clarify what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for seeking clarification, will close this one out though as may have found an alternative.